# How to your load 3D Model (.obj) in Open3D?

Tags: python, 3d-model, open3d

I have a 3D Model (.obj) texture that loads correctly in other software: 
[image]

But with Open3D the texture is all messaged up:
[image]

[image]

Here is the code I'm using:

```
import open3d as o3d

def visualize(mesh):
    vis = o3d.visualization.Visualizer()
    vis.create_window()
    vis.add_geometry(mesh)
    vis.run()
    vis.destroy_window()

def main():
    mesh = o3d.io.read_triangle_mesh("scene_mesh_decimated_textured.obj")
    visualize(mesh)

main()
```

And here is the model and texture:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/xm0sun3hoijwbjf/Archive.zip?dl=0

Comment: https://github.com/intel-isl/Open3D/issues/1484

Comment: Hopefully solved in: https://github.com/intel-isl/Open3D/pull/1517

Comment: Is this solved?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
 mesh = o3d.io.read_triangle_model("scene_mesh_decimated_textured.obj")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).